# Relative positioning of tables in jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

In JasperReports 5.5.0a, are they any parameters I can set to make tables within a report to position itself relative to the length of the preceding table?  Sometimes the data in table1 returns a lot of data that then overlaps table2 directly beneath it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these options
**"Stretch With Overflow"
& "strech type"**
in properties of that particular colunm.